# method that removes all twice duplicate characters in String

Tags: ios, swift, string, character

I wrote a method that removes all 2 duplicate characters in String, for example 
I need delete only char that contains twice, for example
"bndkss" -> "bndk"
"nnmmhj" - > "hj"
"aaabbaac" -> "ac 
"abba" -> ""

I wrote on objc and everything works, but Swift is not working, help please, where did I go wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let string = "baab"
    print("before: \(string)")
    let stringAfter = checkString(string: string)
    print("after: \(stringAfter)")
}

func checkString(string : String) -> String {
    var tempString = string
    for (index, element) in string.characters.enumerated() {

        for (index2, element2) in string.characters.enumerated() {
            if element == element2 && index != index2 {
                if index > index2 {
                    tempString.remove(at: tempString.index(tempString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
                    tempString.remove(at: tempString.index(tempString.startIndex, offsetBy: index2))
                } else {
                    tempString.remove(at: tempString.index(tempString.startIndex, offsetBy: index2))
                    tempString.remove(at: tempString.index(tempString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
                }

                if tempString.characters.count < 1 {
                    return ""
                } else {
                    checkString(string: tempString)
                }
            } else {
                if index == tempString.characters.count - 1 && index2 == tempString.characters.count - 1 {
                    return tempString
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

Updates:
just need

```
return checkString(string: tempString)
```

instead

```
checkString(string: tempString)
```

Comment: Don't add the solution to the question. You can *answer* your own question, or *accept* one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code, such as

- After removing characters in `tempString`, the indices `index` and `index2` to long refer to the original characters in `tempString`.
  Wrong characters are removed as a consequence.
- You call `checkString()` recursively but discard the result.

*Update:* As you already noticed in the meantime, `return checkString(string: tempString)` solves these problems.

Here is an alternative implementation. The idea is to use a dictionary
to remember where a character has been seen last, and an index set
which keeps track of the positions of the characters which are to
be preserved. Instead of two nested loops and recursion, two "simple"
loops are used here, plus the cost of the dictionary and set operations.

```
func removeDuplicateCharacters(string: String) -> String {

    var seen = [Character: Int]()
    var keep = IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<string.characters.count)

    for (idx, c) in string.characters.enumerated() {
        if let prevIndex = seen[c] {
            keep.remove(prevIndex)
            keep.remove(idx)
            seen.removeValue(forKey: c)
        } else {
            seen[c] = idx
        }
    }
    return String(keep.map { string[string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: $0)] })
}
```

Examples:

```
print(removeDuplicateCharacters(string: "bndkss")) // ""bndk" 
print(removeDuplicateCharacters(string: "nnmmhj")) // "jh"
print(removeDuplicateCharacters(string: "abba"))   // ""
print(removeDuplicateCharacters(string: "aaabbaac")) // "ac"
```

Comment: Will this be ordered string. As Set is unordered.?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: The sets are only used to determine which characters occur more than once. The actual filtering is done in the last line, and that preserves the order of the characters.

Comment: Oh.. I missed that one.. Great

Comment: Thank you, your code work well. But I need a different functionality. I need delete only char that contains twice, for example "aaabbaac" -> "ac". I add return when I recursively call func and it works fine.

Comment: @user7092043: OK, then I misunderstood your goal. Perhaps you can update your question and clarify that with more examples.

Comment: @user7092043: based on the example in your previous comment, characters that occur more than twice will be reduced to a single character of the same type in the result string. For such cases, how do your specify where the single remaining characters is to be placed? E.g., for string `"aaabbaacaa"`, is the resulting string `ac` or `ca`?

Comment: @user7092043: Is there a special reason for trying to vandalize my answer? I tried to answer your question as good as possible and updated it after your last comment. If that does not help then I would suggest that you clarify the question to show exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Martin wrote a much cleaner version than myself, but I worked on this for a little while so I figured I'd post it to show you another way it could have been accomplished.

```
func removeDuplicates(from original: String) -> String {
var originalString = original
var newString = ""

for character in originalString.characters {
if !newString.contains("\(character)") {
    newString.append(character)
     originalString = originalString.characters.filter { $0.description != "\(character)" }.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: "")
  } else {
    newString = newString.characters.filter { $0.description != "\(character)" }.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: "")
    }
  }
return newString
}
```